# Libgdx "pack", not working, what I could be doing wrong?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make a window, then use the pack method to get the right size, but the window maximizes instead. Here's my code:

```
private Table buildOptionsWindowLayer() {
    winOptions = new Window("Options", skinLibgdx);
    // (...) building some widgets

    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "pref width is " + winOptions.getPrefWidth());
    // displays: "pref width is 247.0"

    winOptions.pack();

    // move the window
    winOptions.setPosition(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT - winOptions.getWidth() - 50, 50);
    return winOptions;
}
```

The window ends up with a width of 800.0f. Why?

What it is supposed to render:
[image]

What it does render:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give the [pack() documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/WidgetGroup.html#pack--) a read. I believe your .pack is the problem here as it calls the super class' constructor before yours.

Comment: thanks for your answer, sorry I don't think I understand, right now I'm calling this method on the show method for Screen object. Where should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just ran into this same issue.  You can move the pack and position calls to the onOptionsClicked method so they are called after the window is shown.

```
private void onOptionsClicked()
{
    loadSettings();
    btnMenuPlay.setVisible(false);
    btnMenuOptions.setVisible(false);
    winOptions.setVisible(true);

    winOptions.pack();
    winOptions.setPosition(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH - winOptions.getWidth() - 50, 50);
}
```